# How to subset specific rows of a dataframe conditioned to the datetime of another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, lubridate

I have one dataframe (`df1`) with info about a specific variable (`df1$Variable.X`) overtime (`df1$Datetime`). Each value of `df1$Variable.X` is a value representative of a time interval of 50s. `df1$Datetime` represents the initial times for those 50s time intervals. On the other hand, I have a dataframe (`df2`) which has specific datetimes (`df2$Datetime`). Below I create a fake example:

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(Datetime= seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2017-03-08 11:00:00.001", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC"), as.POSIXct("2017-03-08 12:15:00.001", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC"), by = "50 sec", tz="UTC"),
                  Variable.X= sample(x = 1:10, size = 91, replace = TRUE))

df2 <- data.frame(Datetime=c("2017-03-08 11:04:34.546","2017-03-08 11:24:14.646","2017-03-08 11:38:55.098","2017-03-08 11:58:12.023","2017-03-08 12:11:34.546"))


head(df1)
                 Datetime Variable.X
1 2017-03-08 11:00:00.000          5
2 2017-03-08 11:00:50.000         10
3 2017-03-08 11:01:40.000          2
4 2017-03-08 11:02:30.000          2
5 2017-03-08 11:03:20.000          6
6 2017-03-08 11:04:10.000          4

head(df2)
                 Datetime
1 2017-03-08 11:04:34.546
2 2017-03-08 11:24:14.646
3 2017-03-08 11:38:55.098
4 2017-03-08 11:58:12.023
5 2017-03-08 12:11:34.546
```

I would like to subset the dataframe `df1` considering `df2$Datetime`. Specifically, I would like to create a dataframe called `df1.A` in which I have the rows for which `df2$Datetime` is not included in the time interval determined by `df1$Datetime + 50s` and a dataframe called `df1.B` in which I have rows of `df1` for which the `df2$Datetime` is included in the time interval determined by `df1$Datetime + 50s`. Thus, nrow(df1.A) + nrow(df1.B) = nrow(df1).

In this example, `df1.B` would be:

```
df1.B
                 Datetime Variable.X
1 2017-03-08 11:04:10.000          5
2 2017-03-08 11:24:10.000          9
3 2017-03-08 11:38:20.000          9
4 2017-03-08 11:57:30.000          3
5 2017-03-08 12:10:50.000          2
```

Does anyone know how to do it? Data frames in my real case have thousands of rows, so I would need an efficient way to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using non-equi join from `data.table` and extracting the row indices with `which=TRUE`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, later := Datetime + 50]
setDT(df2)

ix <- df1[df2, on=.(Datetime<=Datetime, later>Datetime), which=TRUE]
df1.A <- df1[!ix]
df1.B <- df1[ix]
```

`df1.B`:

```
              Datetime Variable.X               later
1: 2017-03-08 11:04:10          5 2017-03-08 11:05:00
2: 2017-03-08 11:24:10          9 2017-03-08 11:25:00
3: 2017-03-08 11:38:20          9 2017-03-08 11:39:10
4: 2017-03-08 11:57:30          3 2017-03-08 11:58:20
5: 2017-03-08 12:10:50          2 2017-03-08 12:11:40
```

data (note that timezone has to be consistent for the code to work correctly):

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(Datetime= seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2017-03-08 11:00:00.001", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC"), as.POSIXct("2017-03-08 12:15:00.001", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC"), by = "50 sec", tz="UTC"),
    Variable.X= sample(x = 1:10, size = 91, replace = TRUE))

df2 <- data.frame(Datetime=as.POSIXct(c("2017-03-08 11:04:34.546","2017-03-08 11:24:14.646","2017-03-08 11:38:55.098","2017-03-08 11:58:12.023","2017-03-08 12:11:34.546"),
    format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC"))
```

Comment: Thanks @chinsoon12. Can I ask you something? I have tried it in my real case, and got `Error in seq_len(nrow(x))[-irows] : only 0's can be mixed with negative subscribers`. Then I looked at `ix` and I found some `NAs`. This is because I have some time gaps in what here would be `df1`, so I guess that the `NA` is because in some occasions I have a datetime in `df2` but I don't have a time interval for this datetime in `df1`. How could I solve this? Could be a solutions just ran `ix <- ix[!is.na(ix)]` after `ix <- df1[df2, on=.(Datetime<=Datetime, later>Datetime), which=TRUE]`? Thanks again!

Comment: I am not sure what `ix` is, and then, I am not sure if I can just delete the `NAs` from the `ix` object...

Comment: You can pass in nomatch=0 as well to remove NAs. ix are the row indices of df1

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `tidyverse` way :

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(Datetime = lubridate::ymd_hms(Datetime))
df1.B <- df2 %>% 
          rename(dt = Datetime) %>%
          tidyr::crossing(df1) %>%
          filter(between(difftime(dt, Datetime, units = "secs"), 0, 50))

df1.A <- df1 %>% anti_join(df1.B %>% select(-dt))

df1.B
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  dt                  Datetime            Variable.X
#  <dttm>              <dttm>                   <int>
#1 2017-03-08 11:04:34 2017-03-08 11:04:10          5
#2 2017-03-08 11:24:14 2017-03-08 11:24:10          9
#3 2017-03-08 11:38:55 2017-03-08 11:38:20          9
#4 2017-03-08 11:58:12 2017-03-08 11:57:30          3
#5 2017-03-08 12:11:34 2017-03-08 12:10:50          2

nrow(df1.A)
#[1] 86
nrow(df1.B)
#[1] 5
nrow(df1)
#[1] 91
```

However, I think this will not scale well if you have very large data since when we use `crossing` it creates every combination of `df1` with `df2`.

Comment: Thanks for your try @Ronak Shah. You're right. In my real case, df1 is about 30,000 rows and df2 is about 4,000. When I ran your script, Rstudio freezes. Maybe this approach isn't the most appropriate. Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: Check out chinsoon12's non-equi join method using `data.table`. I guess that would be faster.